# How to change position of Use two finger to move map message

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-maps

So currently when the map is open it shows a message to use to fingers to move the map. and this message is currently aligned to center to screen. how to change position of message to top.

**Note - Using google Map API**  into React project.

Please check image for example

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OchbN.png)

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is not configurable through a public interface. It may be possible to use css to reposition the message although not recommended.

A feature request can be submitted at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=787814.